# VS Code path autocomplete to root of OS

Tags: visual-studio-code

My ts project in Visual Studio Code shows this path: `~/` and its suggestion to root of macos, as on screen shoot.

Whats goin on?

[image]

My tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "rootDir": "./",
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "~*": ["./*"]
    },
    "incremental": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": ["dom", "es2015", "webworker"]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, found it.

In tsconfig should be:

```
"paths": {
  "~/*": ["./*"]
},
```

instead of

```
"paths": {
  "~*": ["./*"]
},
```